# How calculate difference from start time until change time in pandas?

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have some data like this:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame ({'id': ['A', 'A','A' ,'B', 'B','B', 'B'],
                         'cahnge' : ['False', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'Flase', 'True', 'False'],
                         'start': ['2017-1-1', '2018-5-5', '2017-5-21', '2017-6-6','2017-7-8','2017-8-9','2018-5-1'],
                        })


╔═══════╦════╦════════╦═══════════╗
║ index ║ id ║ cahnge ║   start   ║
╠═══════╬════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║     0 ║ A  ║ False  ║ 2017-1-1  ║
║     1 ║ A  ║ True   ║ 2018-5-5  ║
║     2 ║ A  ║ False  ║ 2017-5-21 ║
║     3 ║ B  ║ False  ║ 2017-6-6  ║
║     4 ║ B  ║ Flase  ║ 2017-7-8  ║
║     5 ║ B  ║ True   ║ 2017-8-9  ║
║     6 ║ B  ║ False  ║ 2018-5-1  ║
╚═══════╩════╩════════╩═══════════╝
```

and I want to convert it as shown below using pandas:

```
╔═══════╦════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════╗
║ index ║ id ║  start   ║  change  ║ diff ║
╠═══════╬════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════╣
║     0 ║ A  ║ 2017-1-1 ║ 2018-5-5 ║  489 ║
║     1 ║ B  ║ 2017-6-6 ║ 2017-8-9 ║  64  ║
╚═══════╩════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════╝
```

In result the difference between the firs date of each id and the date of change that is true calculated and the second table is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame ({'id': ['A', 'A','A' ,'B', 'B','B', 'B'],
                         'change' : ['False', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'False'],
                         'start': ['2017-1-1', '2018-5-5', '2017-5-21', '2017-6-6','2017-7-8','2017-8-9','2018-5-1'],
                        })
```

**first**, convert to datetime type.
and convert the "True/False" value in the 'change' column to numeric 1, 0.

like this

```py
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['change'] = np.where(df['change']=='False', 0,1)
```

**second**, create start data through `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`.
And you can index the row(with id and date columns) with 1(True) values ​​per id with the following code.

```py
start = df[['id','start']].sort_values(by=['id','start']).drop_duplicates(subset='id').reset_index(drop=True)
print(start)


change = df[['id','start']].loc[df.groupby('id')['change'].idxmax()].rename({'start':'change'},axis=1)
print(change)
```

```
  id      start
0  A 2017-01-01
1  B 2017-06-06

  id     change
1  A 2018-05-05
5  B 2017-08-09
```

**Third**, do a left `merge` two dataframe and calculate the difference between two dates using the `dt` indexer.

```py
final = start.merge(change, how='left', on ='id')
final['diff'] = (final['start'] - final['change']).dt.days
print(final)
```

```
  id      start     change  diff
0  A 2017-01-01 2018-05-05  -489
1  B 2017-06-06 2017-08-09   -64
```

I hope it helps.